# This Javascript is not working in IE or Edge. Anyone got any ideas?

Tags: javascript

I have the following script that copies on select box to the other. It work in chrome,Opera and Firefox but not Edge or IE.

```
<select id="domainsource"><option>yes</option><option>no</option></select>
<select id="domaintarget"><option>yes</option><option>no</option></select>

<script>
var input = document.querySelector('#domainsource');
var messages = document.querySelector('#domaintarget');
input.addEventListener('input', function()
{
messages.value =  input.value;
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? Any error in the console?

Comment: What does Not working mean? Do you get a specific error in the Console?

Comment: use `getElementById` instead of `querySelector` (which is newer), and then drop the `#`.

Comment: `querySelector` has been supported since IE8, as far as MDN reports.  I don't see anything here that is not IE8+ compatible.

Comment: @trincot `querySelector`'s been supported since IE8, I think  it's safe to use

Comment: I changed to getElementById and dropped the #. Still the same... The script still does not copy the value from select1 to select2. Works in Chrome Firefox and Opera still

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me in IE11

```js
var input = document.querySelector('#domainsource');
var messages = document.querySelector('#domaintarget');

function changed() {
  messages.value = input.value;
};
```

```html
<select id="domainsource" onchange="changed()">
  <option>yes</option>
  <option>no</option>
</select>
<select id="domaintarget">
  <option value="yes">yes</option>
  <option value="no">no</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremy !

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this is simply a browser support issue. IE 11 and pre-chromium edge do not support the input event on `select` elements. See note #3 on [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-event).

Comment: Oh I see, :( Is there anyway around this ? Thanks for your reply.